# Detached React Native Expo app, issue connecting to SSL Self Signed Certificate using Feathers.js SocketIO

Tags: android, react-native, socket.io, expo, feathersjs

I have a React Native app built with Expo that I have detached from Expo in order to write some Android Native code - it uses Feathers.js SocketIO to make connections, this works fine with HTTP, however when using HTTPS Self Signed Certificate I get a Socket Connection Timed Out error.

> Socket connection timed out
>
> Stack trace:
>   node_modules/@feathersjs/authentication-client/lib/passport.js:120:25
>   in 
>   node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:152:14 in
>   _callTimer   node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:405:17 in
>   callTimers
>   node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:349:47
>   in __callFunction
>   node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:106:26
>   in 
>   node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:297:10
>   in __guard
>   node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:105:17
>   in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

In my React Native code I make a connection like this:

```
const options = {
  transports: ['websocket'],
  forceNew: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  verify: false,
  secure: true
};

const MOBILE_SERVER_IP = 'https://mypublicIP:3030';

const socket = io(MOBILE_SERVER_IP, options);

// Initilize the feathersClient object
const feathersClient = feathers()
  .configure(socketio(socket))
  .configure(
    auth({
      storage: AsyncStorage,
      timeout: 60000
    })
  );
```

When building the app to test on my Android device from Android Studio along with Expo running on the React Native side I was getting Certificate Chain trust errors previously, until I added the following code to my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
  <application
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

and creating a new file under /res/xml/network_security_config.xml that has this inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/cert"/>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I'm using a Self Signed Certificate for development and this seems to have solved the certificate errors I was getting, however I still am getting Socket Connection Timed out errors when trying to use my app (logging in for example).

Any ideas?